# Python post form with button javascript

Tags: javascript, python, forms, button, mechanize

I try to post ads in a website.
We have 2 forms ,the first form ask me information of ads and is ok i submit them but in second form, to submit i have a button (input) with javacript,

```
onclick="action_cmd('delete')"
```

I use mechanize and python .

The code javascript is :

```
function action_cmd(action){
var hidden = document.getElementById("div_cmd");
hidden.innerHTML += "<>input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cmd\" value=\"" + action + "\">";
document.form_ads_action.submit();
}
```

The code python :
for first form i add the information.

```
br.open("link")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.submit()
```

is ok for first.

for second form:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.submit()
```

doesn't work.

The code HTML :

```
form name="ads_action" action="link" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
input type="image" name="back" id="back" value="Back"   onClick="action_cmd('back');">
input type="image" name="continue" id="continue" value="Val"onClick="action_cmd('delete')">
```

Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You have the same form number:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.submit()
```

If it's different form on the same page, then it should be:

```
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.submit()
```

Or if you want to specifically select the second form, you can do that by name:

```
br.select_form(name = "ads_action")
br.submit()
```